# Spring Cache Key Using Arguments

Tags: spring

I have a class **Person** with properties id, name and age.

I would like to cache Person object using id and name.

my method is 
@Cacheable(value = "person", key = "#p.id + p.name")
**getPerson(Person p)**.

Question is, how do i use cache annotation on getPerson()... something like this.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? you wrote the annotation in the question

Comment: How do i use id and name as key for my method getPerson().

Answer (score 0):

Using the annotation you could concatenate the values to create a key (I read but have not tested tha the debug symbols may be removed and so the parameter should be referenced as "p0").

```
@Cacheable(value="person", key="#p0.id.concat(‘:’).concat(#p0.name)")
```

Otherwise, it will be cached based on Person class equals() and hashCode() just the same way as if you were using the Person object as a key in a Map.

So, for example:

```
public class Person {
    String id;
    String name;
    Number age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```